# boost.asio multi-thread I/O server with async_read

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

The basic logic is as follows

main_thread:

> for(;;) {
>   accept socket
>   async_read head(length of packet),binded to head_handler
>   io_service.run() 
>   }

head_handler(non-thread):

> async_read body(using length read from head) ,binded to body_handler

body_handler(non-thread):

> parse message into Request objects (custom class).
>   push Request to request_pool

read_thread:

> for(;;)  {
>       if request_pool not empty (lock otherwise) {
>            perform actions described by the Request
>       } }

So I have a simple echo server using above logics. It prints out whatever messages passed in.However, only the first message will be displayed, all others will have "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx connected" message printed out correctly.But no messages are printed

Comment: how many handlers does your `io_service` run? This will be the return value of `io_service::run()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not issue any async. operation in `body_handler`, `io_service` runs out of work and `io_service::run()` exits. Before any subsequent call to `io_service::run()` you have to call [`io_service::reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. io_service::reset() did help